# How to query and group certain column in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, filter, unique, google-sheets-formula, google-sheets-query

I need help to do query on Google sheets and to group the result to specific terms, but I don't want to use pivot. Could you please help me? Example sheet with expected result is shown here.

Thank you, really appreciate your help!

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1R8vXCXkURu9RoDOfRVj9inMug9r9hBGZR3qmalf8uQw/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=UNIQUE(FILTER({'Master Data'!D$2:D, 'Master Data'!B$2:B}, 'Master Data'!C$2:C=A1))
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it